# I am getting 'none' printing at the end of every print statement I run. And I am not entirely sure why?

Tags: python

```
def finished_projects(unfinished_projects, completed_projects):
    while unfinished_projects:
        current_project = unfinished_projects.pop()
        print('completing project: ' + current_project)
        completed_projects.append(current_project)

def show_completed_projects(completed_projects):
    print('\nThese projects have been completed:')
    for project in completed_projects:
        print(project)
    

unfinished_projects = ['pie-chart', 'bar graph', 'line chart']
completed_projects = []

print(finished_projects(unfinished_projects,completed_projects))
print(show_completed_projects(completed_projects))
```

Comment: Because you're not returning anything in either function. You're printing from within the function instead.

Comment: Your functions return `None` so when you call, e.g., `print(show_completed_projects(...))` what is printed is the return value which is `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the function don't add print. Just call the function, that's it.

```
def finished_projects(unfinished_projects, completed_projects):
    while unfinished_projects:
        current_project = unfinished_projects.pop()
        print('completing project: ' + current_project)
        completed_projects.append(current_project)

def show_completed_projects(completed_projects):
    print('\nThese projects have been completed:')
    for project in completed_projects:
        print(project)
    

unfinished_projects = ['pie-chart', 'bar graph', 'line chart']
completed_projects = []

finished_projects(unfinished_projects,completed_projects)
show_completed_projects(completed_projects)
```

If you return something then you can use print.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are trying to print the return value of the two function which are None, try do this:

```
finished_projects(unfinished_projects,completed_projects)
show_completed_projects(completed_projects)
```